# Delete unwanted network printers

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Our printers are distributed by Gpos and assigned by computergroups that have (almost) the same name as the printers (e.g. "prn-accounting" etc.).
I'm trying to write a script that looks up the ad printer groups the computer is in and removes the other unwanted network printers. The script is supposed to run at login.

What I can't figure out is how to get the unwanted printers represented in the array $networkPrintersBad. As is the variable $networkPrintersBad is empty...

```
$strName = $env:computername
$printers = @()
$groups = @()
$networkPrintersGood = @()
$networkPrintersAll = @()

# look up LDAP
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=Computer)(Name=$strName))"
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objPath = $objSearcher.FindOne()
$objComputer = $objPath.GetDirectoryEntry()

# remove distinguished name and "-nodefault" from groupname
$groups = (($objComputer.memberOf -replace 'CN=(.+?),(OU|DC)=.+','$1') -replace "-nodefault","")

# filter printer groups
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    if ($group.StartsWith("mfc") -or $group.StartsWith("cop") -or $group.StartsWith("prn") -or $group.EndsWith("armband") -or $group.StartsWith("pdf")) {
        $printers += $group
    }
}
# add path
$networkPrintersGood = $printers | ForEach-Object {"\\srv-print01\$_"}

# get all existing printers from the pc
$networkPrintersAll = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Printer | where {($_.Network -eq ‘true‘)}).name

# problem nr 1
$networkPrintersBad = ($networkPrintersAll | ? ($_ -notin $networkPrintersGood))


Write-Host "All:"
$networkPrintersAll
Write-Host "Supposed to stay:"
$networkPrintersGood
Write-Host "Those that should be removed:"
$networkPrintersBad
# $networkPrintersBad | ForEach-Object { Remove-Printer $_ }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing the curly braces when you are assigning $networkPrintersBad.

```
$networkPrintersBad = $networkPrintersAll | Where-Object ({$_ -notin $networkPrintersGood})
```

Comment: Oh my... That is it (: That's what you get, if you blindly copy from the internet, I guess.

Comment: Since this has resolved your issue can you please accept my answer?  Thanks